# Ошибка npm на windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Пытаюсь выполнить в проекте npm run dev выскакивает ошибка:

```
> spa@1.0.0 dev G:\SPA
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

"cross-env" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! spa@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spa@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-11T14_20_00_056Z-debug.log
```

Попытался выполнить эту команду `npm install --save-dev cross-env`, но в итоге вылазит такая ошибка:

```
npm ERR! path G:\SPA\node_modules\fast-deep-equal\npm-shrinkwrap.json
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'G:\SPA\node_modules\fast-deep-equal\npm-shrinkwrap.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-11T14_21_50_116Z-debug.log
```

Пытался выполнить и от имени администратора, ничего не изменилось. Проверял на вирусы ничего не нашло. Система Windows 8.1, версия npm 5.3.0. На Ubuntu 17.10 `npm run dev` работает нормально. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Добавил package.json:

```
{
  "name": "spa",
  "description": "My first vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "SurokDima",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "jQuery": "^1.7.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш package json

Comment: У вас проблемы с зависимостью spa

Comment: Добавил package.json. А если проблемы с spa то что это такое? Это же просто название моей папки вроде бы. Как это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross env нужен для установки переменной окружения, уберите

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development

из вызова dev скрипта и установите эту переменную вручную

Ps. Cross env не cross)) в отношении 8.1 судя по всему